# Class in c++ is still abstract even if the template class implements the abstract methods

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions

I want to know if it is standard compliant behaviour if the compiler thinks that the instance of the template class is still abstract even if the class to derive from implements this abstract methods.

My compiler is Microsoft C/C++ Compiler 18.00.40629 (Visual Studio 2013)

Gues following class:

```
class MyClass {
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class MyClassT : public MyClass, public T {
};

class MyTemplateData {
    void Method() {
    }
};

MyClassT<MyTemplateData> MyInstance;
```

For my understanding the class `MyClassT<MyTemplateData>` is a valid instance which implements all abstract methods since MyClassT derives from both `MyClass` and `MyTemplateData`. What should I change in order being able to compile this class by keeping desired behaviour?

There is a solution, but let me explain why I don't want following:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClassT : public MyClass, public T {
    void Method() {
        T::Execute();
    }
};
```

In the above case, it would indeed compile, however this would assume that my `T` class always implements `Method`. However what I want is to have an empty `Method` in `MyClassT` instead that should be overriden by the `T::Method` if `T` class implements it.

So following will also compile, however `T::Method` will never gets called.

```
template <typename T>
class MyClassT : public MyClass, public T {
    void Method() {
    }
};

MyClass* Interface = new MyClassT<MyTemplateData>();
Interface->Method(); // <- here, MyTemplateData::Method() gets never called
```

Is there a solution, or is this a compiler specific bug?

**Edit**: Just another example, this time the compiler should exactly know that the derived class implements required abstract methods.

```
struct InterfaceA {
    virtual void MethodA() = 0;
};

struct InterfaceAB : InterfaceA {
    virtual void MethodB() = 0;
};

class ImplA : public virtual InterfaceA {
public:
    void MethodA() {
    }
};

class ImplAB : public virtual InterfaceAB, public ImplA {
    void MethodB() {
    }
};
```

The compiler expects class `ImplAB` to implement `MethodA` since `InterfaceAB` requires both to be implemented `MethodA`and `MethodB`. However since `ImplAB` also derive from `ImplA` and the compiler knows exactly that `ImplA` implementes that interface, there should be no problem at all.

There should be at least a keyword to give the compiler a hint where abstract methods are implemented like in the example below. I don't see any reason why this should be avoided at least if a VTABLE is used any way.

```
class ImplABCD : public implements InterfaceABCD, public ImplA, public ImplB, public ImplC, public ImplC {
};
```

This **implements** keyword would indicate that all abstract methods from `InterfaceABCD` will be implemented in `ImplABCD` **or is already implemented in one of the inherited classes**. If there are signature ambiguities the case is handled as it is already done by the c++ specification when inheriting from multiple classes with the same base classes.

Comment: clang/gcc also doesn't compile this code.

Comment: You're complicating your understanding unnecessarily by keeping CRTP in the picture.  Just consider the equivalent `class X : public MyClass, public MyTemplateData { };` - hopefully you already know and accept that's not a valid way to supply an implementation of a virtual function, but if not let us know and we'll drag in the Standard quotes.

Comment: More generally, it sounds like you can do exactly what you ask for by using SFINAE to check whether `T::Execute` exists - just google `has_member_function`, `has_member` or similar and you should see how.

Comment: @TonyD For my understanding multiple inherited classes can implement/override methods of each other, my be I'm wrong?

Comment: @bkausbk - Yes, you are wrong (for C++). If you inherit from an abstract class, you must implement the pure virtual functions. Even if other base classes also implement it.

Comment: @bkausbk: well, you might want to check on that - e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b022b0eb9ba79665

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to us @ForEveR solution then you can do the following.

Use SFINAE std::enable_if.
Something in the lines of:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyClassT : public MyClass, public T
{
    typename std::enable_if<has_func_method<T>::value, void>::type Method()
    {
        T::Method();
    }

    typename std::enable_if<!has_func_method<T>::value, void>::type Method()
    {
        //do nothing
    }
};
```

EDIT:
You can use the SFINAE on the class itself instead on the inside.
It might be nicer that way.
Here is a working example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct MyClass
{
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

template< typename C, typename = void >
struct has_func_method
  : std::false_type
{};

template< typename C>
struct has_func_method< C, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        decltype( std::declval<C>().Method()),
        void
    >::value
>::type >
  : std::true_type
{};

template <typename T, bool has_method = has_func_method<T>::value>
struct MyClassT : public MyClass, public T
{
};

template <typename T>
struct MyClassT<T, false> : public MyClass, public T
{
    void Method()
    {
        //do nothing
        std::cout << "doing nothing" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct MyClassT<T, true> : public MyClass, public T
{
    void Method()
    {
        std::cout << "calling T::Method" << std::endl;
        T::Method();
    }
};

struct DataWithoutMethod
{
};

struct DataWithMethod
{
    void Method()
    {
        std::cout << "method called" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    MyClassT<DataWithoutMethod> data;
    data.Method();
    MyClassT<DataWithMethod> data2;
    data2.Method();
}
```

Comment: Nice; would be even nicer with `override` ;-)

Comment: This solution indeed seems to be interesting, however isn't the usage of SFINAE a bit "disreputable" (unclean design)?

Comment: @bkaus: It's a massive hack but, then, so is the majority of C++ template metaprogramming.

Comment: Note that the `void` template argument to `std::enable_if` is redundant as that is the default anyway. Maybe you wanted to be explicit about the return type, which is a fine stylistic choice.

Comment: @bkausbk Unfortunately we're stuck with our hacks and workarounds until our projects and compilers start using Concepts.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if it is standard compliant behaviour

Yes.

> if the compiler thinks that the instance of the template class is still abstract

It is.

> even if the class to derive from implements this abstract methods.

It doesn't.

You are not overriding `MyClass::Method`; `T::Method` is unrelated.

Let's get rid of the templates for a moment, because they are irrelevant and distract from the issue:

```
class MyClass {
    virtual void Method() = 0;
};

class MyTemplateData {
    void Method() {
    }
};

class MyClassT : public MyClass, public MyTemplateData {
};
```

Here's the inheritance tree:

```
MyClass  MyTemplateData
    \       /
     \     /
    MyClassT
```

`Method` must be implemented on the left-hand side; that is, either in `MyClass`, `MyClassT`, *or something in between*. The right-hand side is an unrelated inheritance branch: when you created `MyTemplateData::Method`, this did not override `MyClass::Method` because there is no inheritance relationship between `MyTemplateData` and `MyClass`.

*Overriding only works in straight lines.*

Comment: Ok, if this is true, this is a bad design by me and I should change it.

Comment: You said the left branch has to be implemented in order being able to compile. Just for fun I've tried the following: I included `using T::Method;` in my `MyClassT` class. This **should** (if T implements this method) make this method available in `MyClassT`, but even that didn't compiled.

Comment: @bkausbk: "Making it available" is not the same thing as overriding it.